# A sci fi/ horror movie with black stones that cause bad luck/ curse

Tags: story-identification, movie

All i can remember from this movie is that at some point the dad drives to a house where the driveway was made out of those black rocks, and in another scene i think their kid brought one of the black stones in the car and they got in a bad car accident. the movie could have been made around 2012 or even earlier.

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the movie you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[The Darkness](https://youtu.be/FDhoqY1grJY) is a Blumhouse film produced in 2014, starring Kevin Bacon and a bunch of black cursed rocks.

Common elements:
Those cursed black rocks;
A dad (Kevin Bacon);
The kid who brought the rocks and cursed his family members.